# ACA AIR XML - TestFileInd no longer in 7.0 but the pub claims it needs to be there still

Tags: xml, xsd, irs

So in [Publication 5164 (Rev. 11-2015)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5164.pdf) it says in 4.3:

> The
>   Manifest requires that each transmission carry a Test File Indicator (TestFileInd) to indicate if
>   the transmission is a test or production transmission.

However, I cannot find it ANYWHERE in any of the xsd files as of 7.0. I see it in the old 6.2 XSD files however. Do we still need to include this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestFileInd is in fact a remnant of 6.2 and you now only need TestFileCd. I submitted Test Scenario 1 with no issues without it.